# User Access to Quarantined Emails

Tags: email, audit, exchange, quarantine

Are there any industry recommendations with regards to allowing users access to quarantined emails in Office 365? Should users be notified of quarantined emails. Should they be allowed to request the release of quarantined emails? I ask because my company believes that users should not have visibility to these emails. We have had 2 situations now where a very important customer of ours had emails put into quarantine due to a false positive. And since nobody was notified they emails went unanswered and we almost lost a customer. I am looking for industry standards with regard to quarantine emails.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for this. This is entirely a risk assessment by the business. Is the risk of lost emails less than the risk of malicious emails being processed by users?

I agree that preventing people from managing their own emails is restrictive, but that just means that the quarantine needs to be reviewed quite frequently in order to release legitimate emails.

So, in this case, it seems that they put in a restrictive policy without the compensating support for good email flow.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an email quarantine then you should have an automatic bounce-back notification to inform the sender that their email has been quarantined and to provide them with instructions on how to request for the email to be released from the quarantine. The instructions could be simply to contact a staffed mailbox where release requests are picked up by a person who will manually review the quarantined email and release it if appropriate. If you don't have a bounce-back then you have effectively just implemented an email block.

Comment: Inform the *sender* how to get it out of quarantine? The question here is about recipients managing their emails. And how do you suggest that process goes? If I send a malicious email, get your message, and follow the process, then I can get my malicious email through? No. the proper process in this situation is to have someone regularly review the quarantine, analyse the emails, check with all parties, if required, and release legitimate emails. Don't give power to the sender.

Comment: We get hundreds if not thousands of quarantined emails a day. How is it reasonable for someone to review and analyze all of these emails?

Comment: @CJamesEd you missed my point. If this is what your company wants to do (send thousands of emails a day to a central quarantine) then they need to provide the resources to process all those emails. Period. That's it. There's no magic here. If you buy 1000 cats, then you need to feed and clean up after 1000 cats every day. This situation is why most orgs allow people to manage their own quarantine. If your company doesn't accept that risk *then they need to resource their chosen approach*.

Comment: If you are trying to tell us that management expects you to "just take care of it" and not provide resources, then you need to quantify the problem to management. If this is what you are trying to say, then this isn't a security issue but a pure management issue.